# FOSS password vault for workplace teams?

Tags: open-source, password-manager

My requirements are almost identical to those listed [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/enterprise-password-management-password-vault-software).

Specifically:

- Must support encryption of the entire database/collection
- Must allow granular access control to entries or groups of entries
- Must not be cloud-based, as in it must be something we can install on our
  servers, as well as access and manage internally.
- Can import data from standard data formats (xml, csv, xls(x) or KeePass)

Additionally, I require the software to be open source. It can run on any OS, though I would prefer *nix compatibility.

Comment: For Windows I guess?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Edited to include OS requirements.