# Cloud enterprise password manager

Tags: password-manager

Over the years, I've tested many password managers (SPB Wallet, KeePass, Safe In Cloud, LastPass, Dashlane, Passportal, etc) but all have had at least one major drawback and now my employer wants one that we can resell to our clients.

So, I'm looking for a password manager that has the following features in decreasing order of importance (subject to change as I think about it more):

1. Proven security (open source or audited).
2. GDPR-compliant (European) cloud hosting - **not** on-premises hosted.
3. Partner / reseller program.
4. Native Windows, iOS, Android, macOS, etc apps with web browser extensions / plug-ins.
5. Central and per-user databases / vaults.
6. Active Directory integration / Single Sign-On.
7. Custom templates.

I know that LastPass and Dashlane and others have enterprise versions which look very promising but I'm kind of looking for people's actual experiences.

I believe that this is different to [Enterprise password management/password vault software?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/enterprise-password-management-password-vault-software).