# FOSS-SaaS-Gratis, public&&private key generating password management program ("password manager" / "password vault")

Tags: password-manager

I always aspire to memorize all my five most-important-passwords:

- Operating system
- Main email client
- **Password vault (I never used one so far)**
- database root-user password (for the database on which I host my website)
- The password of the *online-service-account* associated with my bank account, in my bank's website

Principally all of these passwords are comprised from at least 12 characters (letters and numbers).

---

Some passwords I store in a file in my (password protected) operating system and if I need to use them I go into that file, copy the password to clipboard and pasting it where I need; I do that mostly with "not-very-used" passwords which I use approximately once in a month, if not say once in a year.

That said;

I desire to start hosting my aforementioned "not-very-used" passwords in a password vault to give them a second layer of defense besides my operating systems password and to finally get acquainted with password vaults which several people I regard as information security experts recommended using or at least said that under some circumstances they could be very secure (public&&private key utilization as described below).

---

Please share with us your recommendation for a password management program ("password manager"/"password vault") which is:

- [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software)
- [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)
- Gratis (doesn't cost money to be used)
- [Public && Private authentication-key generating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
- [You don't own and/or maintain and/or promote it for any monetary payment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity_(philosophy))

[BTW, this is not for an enterprise but for me a personal user (which might one day have some social enterprises)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/enterprise-password-management-password-vault-software).